# Regular Expression match text within brakets: [[text]]

Tags: c#, .net, regex, expression

I am trying to write a regular expression that would work in c# that would match something on the lines of

```
[[text is here]]
```

Pretty much anything can go inbetween the `[[`  and `]]`.

The only rule is that if a `[` or `]` shows up,
there can never be more than 1 in a row.

For example

```
[[ text ] is here ]] is a match
[[ text [ is ]here [ ]] is a match
[[ text ][ is [] ]] is a match

[[ text [[ is here]] is NOT a match.
```

I've been scratching my heads for hours and the closest I've come up with is

```
@"\[\[[^\[]+(\]\])+?"
```

The above will match

```
[[text is ] here]]

but not

[[text is [ here]]
```

Any help/insights would be appreciated.

Comment: I have my doubts a regex is going to cut the mustard here, but a simple parser would be easy to write.

Comment: I agree with Matt. Ditch RegEx's here. It will be quite complicated and you will have to wrap your head around it anew each time you want to change it. A simple for loop through each char of the string will be easier to understand, change, and much faster computationally.

Answer (score 2):

```
\[\[(?:[^\[\]]|\][^\]]|\[[^[])*\]\]
```

Expanded:

```
\[\[           # match the [[
(?:            # and then match zero or more...
   [^\[\]]     #   character which is not [ or ], or
|  \][^\]]     #   a ], followed by a non-], or
|  \[[^[]      #   a [, followed by a non-[
)*
\]\]           # and match the ]]
```

Note that this will match `[[ text [[ is here]] is NOT a match.` with `[[ is here]]`.

Comment: This returns a partial match against the string "[[ text [[ is here]]", which should not be a match according to the requirements. The string "[[ is here]]" is matched.

Comment: @jmacinnes: If complete match is needed then just stick the `^...$` to the regex.

Comment: That will definitely work, but it does assume the text to match isn't embedded in other text, which is neither confirmed nor denied by the question.

Comment: Correctamundo! +1  I would only add that the efficiency can be improved by _"unrolling-the-loop"_ as follows: `\[\[[^\[\]]*(?:(?:\][^\]]|\[[^[])[^\[\]]*)*\]\]`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you will need to break it up into two regexps, one testing for the `[[ ]]` part, and the other looking for the "bad" condition about two in a row.  A "match" is matching on the first one and not the second.

**EDIT** or use KennyTM's superior solution

Answer (score 0):

You will need positive look ahead and look behind.

```
(?<=\[\[).*?(?=\]\])
```